# ModuleNotFoundError when importing package that is installed in conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, flask, anaconda, conda, flask-migrate

Unable to import flask-migrate dependencies that are missing python version/sub-version from build version (3rd column of conda list output).

Flask-migrate was installed from conda-forge using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge flask-migrate
```

Several dependencies were installed simultaneously and are found in `conda list -n venv` but cannot be imported to python.

[image: venv conda list]

```
(venv) C:\Users\Colin\Documents\Projects\microblog>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import alembic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alembic'
```

From what I have found, the packages that are raising ModuleNotFoundErrors upon import are all missing the python version in the 3rd column of conda list.

**Successfully import: py36_0 or py36_1000 or py36* etc.**

**ModuleNotFoundError: py_0 or py_1**

Why are installed packages raising `ModuleNotFoundError` when imported to python?

Comment: Try manually activating the venv and pip install alembic?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the packages with py_0 environment were all installed as Noarch packages from conda. I'm not sure why my system is unable to import the Noarch packages but I was able to work around the problem by manually downloading the win64-py36_0.tar.bz2 files and installing them locally using:

```
conda install /package-path/package-filename.tar.bz2
```