# Can't import package that is installed in conda environment

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, conda

There are similar previous questions, e.g. [Can't import package after installing in a conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65976231) or [ModuleNotFoundError when importing package that is installed in conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55230041), but I couldn't find a solution that worked in any of the existing questions.

I have a conda env called 'keras', and I installed various packages, including keras in it. E.g. if I try to install Keras again I get:

```
C:\Users\Ori Family>conda activate keras

(keras) C:\Users\Ori Family>conda install -c conda-forge keras
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

But the module is not actually available. E.g.:

```
(keras) C:\Users\Ori Family>python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from keras.models import Sequential
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Everything seems to be in order:

```
>>> import platform
>>> print(platform.architecture())
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...   print(p)
...

C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\python39.zip
C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\DLLs
C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\lib
C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras
C:\Users\Ori Family\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\lib\site-packages
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\python.exe
```

I'm using conda 4.11.0, and `conda list -n keras` has this line in the output:

```
keras                     2.6.0            py39hd3eb1b0_0
```

Any tips on how to solve/diagnose/debug this?

Comment: Have you looked in `C:\tools\anaconda3\envs\keras\lib\site-packages` to see if there's a folder named `keras` in there, with all the appropriate content?

Comment: Thanks. There's `keras_preprocessing` and `Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2.dist-info`, but no `keras`.
If this is a problem, why don't I get any error when trying to install keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Tensorflow and to change the way you import Keras -> `tensorflow.keras.models`.

```sh
# create a fresh env for keras
conda create -c conda-forge -n keras python=3.7 keras tensorflow
# use the env
conda activate keras
```

Then you can import it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
print(f"{keras.__version__}")
# 2.6.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using an old tutorial that isn't compatible with tf2. Not sure why it would let me install, but not import afterwards. These should work together...